# Handler to see if Page was launched before being suspended

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I'm building an app with a `SecondaryTile` to launch it with some parameters.

I need a way to know if the `MainPage` was launched from the `SecondaryTile`, so I'm trying to see if there are some `Argument` using the `OnNavigatedTo` method.

The problem is that this event gets fired only if the app was launched from a suspended state, and this means that the event is not fired if I press the Windows button and then I tap on the tile before 10 seconds.

The same applies to the `Loaded` event and the `NavigationHelper_LoadState` hanlder, so I don't know how to let the page know that it was launched from the `SecondaryTile`.

I know that I can get this information from the `App`'s `OnLaunched` event but I still don't know how to pass it to the `MainPage` because seems like there's no method that gets called after the page has been shown.

Even the [sample provided by Microsoft](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/secondary-tiles-sample-edf2a178/) fails at this because it uses the constructor and the `OnNavigatedTo` handler, and I've no idea on how to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `OnNavigatedTo` doesn't get fired when the app is launched from a previous `Running` state I had to force the navigation with this code in the `OnLaunched` method of `APp.xaml.cs`:

```
if (rootFrame.Content == null)
{
    // Default generated code
}
else
{
    if (e.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Running)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Arguments))
            if (!rootFrame.Navigate(typeof (MainPage), e.Arguments))
            {
                 throw new Exception("Failed to create initial page");
            }
    }
}

// Ensure the current window is active.
Window.Current.Activate();
```

This allows the `OnNavigatedTo` method to be fired, so I can manage the situation in which the app has been launched from the secondary tile.

(I don't know if the pasted code works because I had to change it before pasting but that's the idea)

Answer (score 1):

Store the activation args inside the `App` class...

```
internal static LaunchActivatedEventArgs LaunchArgs = null;
protected override async void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
{
  LaunchArgs = e;

  // rest of method
```

...and read them from the `OnNavigatedTo` method of the target page ("Scenario 5" from the sample you linked to):

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
  if (App.LaunchArgs != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(App.LaunchArgs.Arguments))
    InputText.Text += Environment.NewLine + "Launched from secondary tile" 
      + Environment.NewLine + DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss");
  else
    InputText.Text += Environment.NewLine + "No launch info available" 
      + Environment.NewLine + DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss");

  // rest of method
```

Note that if you support other activation kinds (file, protocol, etc) you will need to null out the `LaunchArgs` field in those cases.

Comment: The `OnNavigatedTo` method doesn't fire if the app is resuming from a `Running` state. I had to force the navigation in the `OnLaunched` method, check my answer